# How to subset a shapefile

Tags: r, shapefile

The data set of shapefile "Property1A" is:

```
 df
#      suburb        area asst
# 0     Te Aro   14.541780 R076
# 1     Te Aro    7.655428 R076
# 2     Te Aro 3189.976134 <NA>
# 3     Te Aro  242.173386 0132
# 4     Karori  537.697290 R003
# 5    Pipitea 1116.954993 R105
# 6    Mt Cook  106.099900 R151
# 7     Te Aro   83.307421 R057
# 8 Aro Valley  544.665788 R105
# 9 Aro Valley   59.726882 R110
```

When I try to subset the shapefile for suburb "Te Aro", the code I use is:

```
TeAro <- subset(Property1A, suburb == "Te Aro")
```

But there is an error:

```
TeAro <- subset(Property1A, suburb == "Te Aro")
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'suburb' not found
```

Why there is an error?

Comment: A reproducible example please. Did you create an object called `Property1A` (your example suggests you have an object called `df`)? How did you read this shape file in?

Comment: df <- Property1A@data

Comment: Property1A is a shapefile

Comment: By the way, how to edit the format of my question. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "Property1A" is a shapefile. How did you read it into `R`?

Comment: library(rgdal)    
library(shapefiles)

Comment: # library(rgdal)    
# library(shapefiles)
# Property1A <- readOGR(".", "Properties_1A")

There are four files making up a shapefile, a dbf file, a sbn file, a shp file and a shx file.
I read the shapefile into R and use ShapeFileName@data to get the data containing in the shapefile. I check the data in the shapefile and can affirm that there is variable "suburb" including in the data, but I feel confused why I cannot subset the shapefile by "suburb".

Comment: `Property1[Property1$suburb %in% "Te Aro",]`

Comment: Ok, got it. Perhaps it's a polygon shapefile, while I try TeAro <- subset(Property1A, Property1A$suburb == "Te Aro"). It works.

Comment: @Pascal: Thanks. I feel quite confused. Before I ever tried to subset the line shapefile, and the code above works. Why there is an error this time? Because the shapefile is SpatialPolygons?

Comment: Its **NOT** a shapefile. Its something read in from a shapefile. Its a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` - you can create these from all sorts of spatial data objects and databases, not just shapefiles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`subset` with names should work. You don't need the `shapefiles` package if you are reading in with `readOGR`:

```
> require(rgdal)
Loading required package: rgdal
Loading required package: sp
rgdal: version: 0.8-14, (SVN revision 496)
Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 1.9.0, released 2011/12/29
Path to GDAL shared files: /usr/share/gdal/1.9
Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012, [PJ_VERSION: 470]
Path to PROJ.4 shared files: (autodetected)
```

Get the 169 polygons of Indian states into a spatial object:

```
> India = readOGR(".","india_state")
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: ".", layer: "india_state"
with 169 features and 3 fields
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
```

Now subset by name:

```
> Gujarat = subset(India, NAME=="Gujarat")
> dim(Gujarat)
[1] 12  3
> dim(India)
[1] 169   3
```

I can plot these objects, they map nicely:

```
> plot(Gujarat)
```

Without your data or knowing what version of R and the packages you have, there is no way of knowing why this fails for you.

Package: rgdal
Version: 0.8-14

Package: sp
Version: 1.0-14

R version 3.0.2....