# How can I filter a shapefile in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to filter specific zones from this shapefile. The shapefile contains traffic zones from the 2016 TTS survey for the entire GTHA. I downloaded the shapefile from here: http://dmg.utoronto.ca/survey-boundary-files#2006_zone.

I am only interested in zones within Hamilton (5001-5252). I am having trouble with the code.

I am able to plot the shapefile, but cannot filter the zones that I am interested in to plot. I have loaded dplyr and sf packages, and tried using the code below:

```
hamilton <- gtha %>% filter(GTA06 >=5001 & GTA06 <=5252)
```

I keep getting the following message:

Error: object 'GTA06' not found

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subset a shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985395/how-to-subset-a-shapefile)

Comment: Without us having to download and read in the whole shapefile, are you certain that GTA06 is a column in an object that could be used with `filter`, e.g. an `sf` object?

Comment: How did you read the shapefile? What is the class of `gtha`? Are you using `sp` of `sf` package? Are you sure `GTA06` is the name of an attribute? Please edit your question to make it answerable.